# Hadoop hive table not getting repaired with msck

Tags: hive

I have done a distcp of data from a partition to a place in hive ware house which is a diff partition table with same structure but when m doing msck it's exiting with arror code 1.. kindly guide

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling logging on hive cli. Rerun msck command by enabling logging. Will know why it failed.

hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=INFO,console